# VB.net NVarchar SQL Server Parameters Error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, runtime-error, parameter-passing

i'm trying to execute a stored procedure that receives a NVARCHAR parameter from VB.NET

i have the following VB code for make that(i've omitted some parts of my code as connection, else works perfect.):

```
Dim paramCoordenadasConcesion(1) As SqlParameter

paramCoordenadasConcesion(1).ParameterName = "@latitud"
paramCoordenadasConcesion(1).DbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar
paramCoordenadasConcesion(1).Value = latitud

Dim registros As New DataSet
Dim adaptador As New SqlDataAdapter

adaptador.Fill(registros)
```

My SQL Server Stored Procedure structure looks like this

```
procedure [dbo].[prCoordenadasConcesion](@latitud nvarchar(20))
```

The problems appear when i make `adaptador.Fill(registros)`
the error message is `Error al convertir el valor del parámetro de String a Int64.` and the `latitud` variable value is `42° 1' 12,43''`

PD : Executing directly on database works without problems.

If somebody can to help me i'd appreciate him.
Regards!

Comment: How about some of the code in the procedure?

Comment: update coordenadasconcesion
set estado = 'A'
where latitudcoordenada = @latitud

Comment: What about datatypes? I am willing to help but you have to provide some details. What is the datatype for latitudcoordenada?

Comment: column datatype is NVARCHAR(20), when i execute this procedure directly in database with the same value, it works without problems...but when i call it from vb.net it crushes. i think datatype may be the problem because other procedures runs perfectly from vb.net.

Comment: Well here is the issue. I can't see your screen and you are not providing many details. The error is because something is attempting to convert your parameter to an Int64. Unless you provide some details that is about all I can tell you.

Comment: do you have some email for send you the source code?, this is a government's project, therefore, i can't to make anything public because i could lose my employee. but i could send you an email with the whole involved code. many thanks!

Comment: We don't need all the code but enough of it to see what you are doing. You have a variable in .NET but we don't know what the datatype is.